# laravel curl not working on azure

Tags: php, python, laravel, azure, curl

I am connecting my two apps (laravel with python) using curl command. It is working absolutely fine on my local server without changing a single line but when it gives me following error when on azure server

> POST https://myweb.com/searchJobs 500 ()

my code is

```
$ch = curl_init();

    //URL to send the request to

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://python-scrapper-python001.azurewebsites.net/myfunction');

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json'));

    //We are doing a post request
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    //adding the post data to request
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_json);

    //Return instead of outputting directly
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $output = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
```

is there any security protocol that I need to update on azure or what can be possible issue?

Comment: 500 usually tell you there is something wrong with your code

Comment: did you enable debug mode?

Comment: no. actually same code is working fine on local

Comment: enable debug mode and paste the errors here

Comment: MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php (line 251)

Comment: check your routes,make sure you have the right type of request

Comment: yes i do have, i have checked and again if it wasn't there it would have not been working on localhost as well and thanks for trying to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually these lines were working fine on localhost but not on azure

```
$arr = "";
$arr['hello'] = '7';
```

so I changed them as

```
$arr = [];
$arr['hello'] = '7';
```

Though i don't no why azure didn't run it. If php convert it to an array on localhost than it must run on azure as well

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the default domain provided by azure appservice. Instead of just using the HTTP protocol try to use the HTTPS since this is already free on the default domain provided. in this case try this changes.

```
$ch = curl_init();

    //URL to send the request to

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://python-scrapper-python001.azurewebsites.net/myfunction');

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json'));

    //We are doing a post request
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    //adding the post data to request
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_json);

    //Return instead of outputting directly
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $output = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
```